# Why does compression process takes longer than extraction process?

Tags: compression, zip, algorithm

Whenever we compress a file with any method be it zip, rar, 7z, why does compression process takes more time than extraction?

Comment: Many modern compression algorithms are generally dynamic, and will attempt to find the best way to compress the data. That adds time to the initial compression. unless you are dealing with constant IO like a compressed hard disk in-use (where you are compressing often, rather than once), it makes sense that optimizing for extract rather than compress would be a winning proposition for most usecases.

Comment: I disagree with the way this was put by @FrankThomas.  In ALL COMPRESSION, the data needs to be searched through for patterns that can be referenced elsewhere (aka dictionary), thats how compression works.  Compression is ***nondeterministic***.  Decompression requires no "searching".. the algorithm to put the data back already knows where the bits go.  Decompression is ***deterministic***.

Comment: Its not the @FrankThomas was wrong, it is just that it didn't answer your question and his point (howbeit true and valid) has *very little* (not nothing) to do with why one operation takes longer than the other.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain how it is that my first two sentences didn't come across as saying exactly what you said (albeit targeted to a person who hasn't learned about concepts like determinism), but clearly I have failed to communicate effectively, so, sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact reason depends on specific compression algorithm, but the bottom line is:

**There's more than one way to compress a file correctly, but only one way to decompress it correctly.**

Compression is finding a way to express the same information using less data units. What approaches are available depends on particular compression algorithm, but in almost all of them (except for trivial and situational ones like [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)) there are multiple valid solutions. The compression algorithm has to find patterns in the data that can be exploited to compress it. More sophisticated patterns may yield better results, but they will be harder to find - ie. it will take more time and/or memory.

With decompression, on the other hand, there's only one answer: you want to get the original file back. This algorithm is quite different than compression, because it's basically interpreting the compressed file as a list of instructions how to produce the original file.

Fun fact: in extreme cases decompression can be slower than compression. One situation that comes to mind is when you have an extremely compressible, but also quite large file on a storage that reads significantly slower than the CPU can compress data, and writes even slower. In this situation both the compression and decompression will be bottlenecked by the storage and reading it (for compression) will be faster than writing it (for decompression).